# Is there a function that find same values in another two arrays or lists?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

if I have [1, 2, 4] and [1, 3, 4],
`[1, 2, 4] and [1, 3, 4] -> [1, 4](find same value)`
I want to return [1, 4](same value).
is there a function like this example?
please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ.

```
ArrayOne.Intersect(ArrayTwo);
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) method,

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences.

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 4 };
int[] arr2 = { 1, 3, 4 };

var result = arr1.Intersect(arr2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

**Output:**

```
1
4
```

<sub>**Note:** Resultant array will contain all distinct numbers</sub>

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dVmJ1F)

---

**Alternate way:**

If you want duplicate elements as well, then you can try using combination of [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-6.0) and [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.contains?view=net-6.0#system-collections-ilist-contains(system-object)),

```
var result = arr1.Where(x => arr2.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EINBwy)